# How do i config ssl artifacts in a spring application?

Tags: spring, ssl, apache-kafka

I am looking for help involving a spring application ( someone else's design ) that uses kafka consumers and producers.
The design allows for a config.properties file that contains an entry like so:

kafkaAddress=10.10.10.12:9093,10.10.10.11:9093,10.10.10.10:9093

Such config is picked up by some kind of **spring bean** code like this...

Java code...

```
private String kafkaAddress;

public String getKafkaAddress() {
   return kafkaAddress;
}

public void setKafkaAddress(String kafkaAddress) {
   this.kafkaAddress = kafkaAddress;
}
```

And it shows up in a Properties object I see with debugger.

"kafkaAddress" -> "10.10.10.12:9093,10.10.10.11:9093,10.10.10.10:9093"

The code passes the Properties object to constructor of the Kafka client

I thought this all happened through the design of spring and matching config "kafkaAddress" with a String of matching name kafkaAddress

Well I want to config for ssl such things as ...

ssl.truststore.location=C:\some\path\kafka.client.10.10.10.11.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=mySecretWord

I put such things in config but what do i put for my setter and getter?

I can't put String ssl.truststore.location, right?

Answer (score 0):

In config.properties I use ...
   ssl_truststore_password=mySecretPassword

In setters and getters in MyConsumerConfig.java file I use...

```
public void setSsl_truststore_password(String ssl_truststore_password ) {
    this.ssl_truststore_password = ssl_truststore_password;
}
public String getSsl_truststore_password() {
    return this.ssl_truststore_password;
}
```

Before call to constructor .java file I ...

```
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(myConsumerConfig.getSsl_truststore_password())) {
        consumerProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,
                onlineConsumerConfig.getSsl_truststore_password());
    }
```

The SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG is defined in package org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs ...

```
public static final String  SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG  "ssl.truststore.password"
```

The spring framework links the "ssl_truststore_password" in the config file to the getters and setters such as ...

```
MyConsumerConfig.setSsl_truststore_password(String ssl_truststore_password)
```